# Creating a background service that launches an app at a specific time.

Tags: java, android

I just started on android development and I'm trying to write and a service that runs in the background and will launch an app at a specific time.

The program I wrote is based on a tutorial I came across, basically the app has 2 buttons, a start and stop. Once the user presses the start button, it'll start the background service and will check the time and if the time is right, it'll launch the app.

However I noticed that it doesn't always checks the time, it only does it when the user presses the button. How do I make it so that, it'll keep checking the time, once the user presses the button?.

Here is my code. 
**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startApp("com.example.myApp");
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public void startApp(String packageName){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        if(strDate == "09:00" || strDate == "15:00" || strDate ==  "21:00"){
            Toast.makeText(this,strDate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Starting the App",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if(intent != null){
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //start the service
    public void onClickStartServie(View V)
    {
        //start the service from here 
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
    //Stop the started service
    public void onClickStopService(View V)
    {
        //Stop the running service from here
        //Service will only stop if it is already running.
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: So if I make an alarm to start at 9 am and then every 6 hours after that and put that in the StartApp function, will it run indefinitely in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using alarm manager will be a better option. Set an alarm for that time and receive broadcast in your receiver at that time like below code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AppConstants.ALARM_ID_TESTING, new Intent(
            AppConstants.FILTER_TESTING), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + millisAfterCurrent, pendingIntent);
```

Add receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver
android:name=“TestReceiver"
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="filter.test.time” />
</intent-filter>
```

And receiver class as:

```
class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       if (intent.getAction().equals(AppConstants.FILTER_TESTING))
       {
          // code here
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this whole android dev, where would I put the alarm manager initialization bit? Does that go in `MyService.java` ?

Comment: No, no need to use the service, place it where you want to start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try Time Changed Receiver instead of service, Since using a background service is bad programming approah.A service keeps on running in background and takes a lot of system memory and a burden battery. Moreover system can stop any of extra services running at anytime for adjustment of memory issues.

A time change receiver is the best approach and in that you can compare time and open any app accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you this two ways:

1. Use the "new" [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) as replacement for [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Example:

```
int threadCount                     = 1;
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor service = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(threadCount);
long initialDelay   = 5; 
long period         = 10;

ScheduledFuture<?> task = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // DO IT EVERY 10 SECONDS
    }

}, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

[...]

//if you want you can cancel the task later 
task.cancel(true); // mayInterruptIfRunning = true
```

*Since Activities, Threads and Processes can be terminated anytime by Android OS it is not guaranteed that the job is always executed.*

2. Therefore, it is better to use AlarmManager

   - Official howto: [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)
   - Another nice example: [Repeat Alarm Example In Android Using AlarmManager](http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)